# Can you create a title case function in Vega-Lite?

Tags: vega-lite, title-case

is there a way to create or add a title case function in Vega-Lite? I've tried using [this Vega Documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) and am currently using a "hacky" way to get Title Case with a replace function, but I'd like to use a more sustainable/acceptable way for getting this done. Below is the current code I'm using, which is temporarily okay but not sustainable:

`{"calculate": "replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(datum['classification'],'_',' '),'_',' '),'_',' '),'all','All'),' r',' R'),' j',' J')","as": "Classification"}`